# Meteor materialize:materialize sass error

Tags: node.js, meteor, materialize

Can some please tell why am i getting this error when trying to use the materialize:materialize package . I have node-sass installed. And kola is also install on my machine.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\alexi\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.1_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\alexi\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.1_1\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-sass@3.2.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.2.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.2.0\plugin.compileScss.os.windows.x86_32\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScss\compileScss\node_modules\.temp-cwxlp8\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Could be an error in the way you are importing materialize? It looks like its the `fourseven:scss` SCSS compiler is failing judging by the `C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\fourseven_scss\3.2.0\plugin.compileScss.os.windows.x86_32\npm\node_modules\meteor\compileScss\compileScss\node_modules\.temp-cwxlp8\npm-debug.log` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using npm modules so, You can create one with npm init. Make sure to define a "start" script inside it too before running npm start.
OR 
installed "windows-build-tools"
meteor update
meteor update --all-packages
meteor add materialize:materialize
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply still getting the same error im afraid

Answer (score 0):

Try adding fourseven:scss first

```
meteor add fourseven:scss
```

than

```
 meteor add materialize:materialize
```

Worked for me.